# Is there any way to quickly print a TIF image in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, printing

Ok, so in Outlook 2003 printing an attached TIF was as easy as clicking Print.  With Outlook 2007, we have to open the TIF in Picture and Fax viewer, then click the print icon, and then click through half a dozen options in the printing wizard.

Anyone know of any tricks to print an attached TIF easily?

Answer (score 2):

If you go to print an email, there is a checkbox under print options to "Print attached files." It will still bring up the Windows Picture and fax viewer though.

A quick way to avoid the print wizard. When it opens in Picture and Fax viewer, the second to last icon on the bottom is the "Closes this program and open for editing (Ctrl-E)". Click that and it will open to edit (in paint), then you can quickly go to print and go with no wizard.

Comment: Clicking this box prompts to open or save the attachment, and I still have to go through the wizard.

Comment: Hmmm, yah it worked kinda odd on my end too. Let me test something else. It does have a note about attachments being only able to print on default printer. hmmm

Comment: Added some more to my answer...

Answer (score 1):

**[EHow's guide to Avoiding the Photo Print Wizard](http://www.ehow.com/how_4465137_disable-photo-printing-wizard.html)**

**- Step 1**
Be sure you really want to turn off this feature. The purpose of the Photo Print Wizard is to help you print exactly what you want, and to avoid costly mistakes, such as printing a high-res digital picture in enough pieces to build a poster instead of a single sheet. If your printing needs change often, consider giving the wizard another chance.

**- Step 2**
Make sure your default printer is correct. If you're allowed to make changes to the computer in question, access this setting within the Control Panel. Sometimes problems occur when the wrong printer or fax is selected.

**- Step 3**
Choose an alternate program to handle files that are triggering the Photo Print Wizard. For example, find any .JPEG file in any folder using Windows Explorer and right-click on it to choose the program that will be used to open that type of file. On many computers, Windows Picture and Fax Viewer is the default for photo files.

**- Step 4**
Use a shortcut. You can change the programs associated with any of your file types through the menu tabs in Windows Explorer. Choose Tools, then Folder Options, then File Types. This is an easier way to handle photo files, because you will need to change the setting for all file extensions you use, such as .jpg, .gif and .bmp.

**- Step 5** 
Test your new setting. If an attempt to print a file no longer launches the Photo Print Wizard, then you are all set. Otherwise, consider taking more drastic measures.

**- Step 6**
Disable the Windows Picture and Fax program. More advanced users can turn off the program responsible for launching the Photo Print Wizard: Type msconfig at the Run prompt of your Start menu. From there, you can toggle this or any other program item between active and inactive from the Startup list on the last tab. You might also need to type the following at the Run command prompt: regsvr32 /u shimgvw.dll.

That should work!

Comment: First thought you meaned you couldn't get direct printing options. But turned out it's the photo print wizard...

Comment: Ivo just had to crush my answer. haha. Yah I was thinking of switching the default application as a last resort if nothing else could work.

Comment: The only problem with this is finding an alternative program to open TIF files properly (pagination, etc).